# Remove appended previous data after event change

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a ton of code but I'll only show the part that I'm currently stuck on. What I'm trying to fix is when I append data to my table, and change the event, the previous data also gets appended to the new data in my table. I understand that there is a lot of articles on SO about this and I looked them up where some have suggested using `detach()`. But I don't want to append the data later on so that doesn't apply to me. I also tried to use `remove()` and it works but on event change, it removes the data immediately before the data initially gets loaded in.

I have no console errors and everything is wrapped in `document.ready()` function

What I want to achieve:

On event change, Load data if user changes input, delete previous data from previous event and load in the new data from the current event.

Here is my code:

```js
var renameLocations;

switch(picker.chosenLabel){
  case "Example event1":
    renameLocations = [];

    dataLabel = <?php echo json_encode($locations) ?>;
    dataCount = <?php echo json_encode($count) ?>;

    var locationsPHP = <?php echo json_encode($locations) ?>;
    var countPHP = <?php echo json_encode($count) ?>;

    locationsPHP.forEach(function(item, i){
      //$('table#relevantdataModal').find('tbody').innerHTML = '';

      // This works but it deletes the data immediately on event change Rather than loading in data and deleting it later...

      $('table#relevantdataModal').find('tbody').remove();
      $('table#relevantdataModal').find('tbody').append('<tr><td>' + locationsPHP[i] + '</td><td>' + countPHP[i] + '</td></tr>');
    });
  break;
  
  case "Example event2":
    renameLocations = [];

    dataLabel = <?php echo json_encode($todaylocations) ?>;
    dataCount = <?php echo json_encode($todaycount) ?>;
  break;
} // End switch statement
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than remove( ) and append () you may want to try innerHTML for vanilla JavaScript.  In jQuery this is also done with a .html().

In your case it would be:  $('table#relevantdataModal').find('tbody').html(...add your stuff...)

Here are some quick W3 references for the vanilla JS and jQuery.

Vanilla JS - W3
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_element_innerhtml

jQuery - W3
https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_html_set

Comment: Appreciate the advice. However, when I added `html` it still immediately deleted the data on event change. I have an idea though. My table is inside of a bootstrap modal I'm going to try and see if I can only remove the data if the modal is hidden and if it is brought back up again, add back in the data.

Comment: You can have your event listener clear the modal body and then use the .html() to drop in the entire HTML code you need.  lastly have the function from the event listener open the modal. The empty() method may be useful here.  https://api.jquery.com/empty/  Good Luck.